# How to PROPERLY show ProgressBar for a Webview while loading

Tags: android, android-layout, webview

I wan't to indicate that my webview is loading in some way. Using the Progressbar seems like a good solution but I am not certain how to properly do this.
By Progressbar I mean a spinning thingie in Android.

This is what I know by now and what I have tried:
I know about onPageStarted(...) and onPageFinished(...) callbacks which you define inside the WebViewClient and then hide or show Progressbar based on calls to those methods. BUT this approach is creating many problems with the HTML page inside the webview. For example when I hide Progressbar HTML elements resize and than go back to their original sizes for a brief moment. This looks really ugly and I don't know why this is happening. I tried putting my Progressbar and webview inside Frame and Relative layout (in order to have the progress cantered) and with both of these I get the above problem. HTML page loading is Javascript heavy since there is http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4 library on it but I doubt it's the problem with the library since the same page loads without strange behaviours when opened in Browser app on the phone.

My main problem is that I don't know how to define a layout containing my Progressbar and webview and avoid strange zoom in/out jumps. That is why I am asking how should one show progress bar correctly over a webview.

EDIT:
This is one of the layouts I tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

</FrameLayout>
```

It's more or less similar with relative layout but I use centerInPerent=true on both axes for the ProgressBar

Comment: Can you post your layout xml ?

Comment: Will add it in the EDIT in few minutes. View EDIT.

Answer (score 1):

There's an efficient way to show progress in an activity. If you are using `ActionBar`, then 
you can set an INDETERMINATE progressbar (the spinning one), or a horizontal progressbar (as seen on web browsers like Chrome). To do this you have to set the Window Feature to appropriate values like:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
```

OR

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
```

To set the progress value, do this:

```
setFeatureInt( Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);
```

Then call `setProgress(int)` whenever you want to change the progress value.

You can controll the visibility of the progressbar using

```
setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true); //sets it to visible
```

AND

```
setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false); //hides the progressbar
```

Comment: Thank you for information about this other method. Unfortunately I cannot use it in current project but it might find it's place in the future.

Answer (score 0):

FrameLayout is designed to block out an area on the screen to display a single item. Generally, FrameLayout should be used to hold a single child view.

I would use a RelativeLayout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This should work...

Comment: Thank you for the info.Isn't the FrameLayout recommended way to have layered layouts (one element over another)? This Relative layout that you showed is exactly the other one I have tried, but it was also giving me strange zoom in/out bugs. How should I hide ProgressBar in this layout, using GONE or INVISIBLE I tried both and still encounter zoom bug but I might have missed something?